# "It’s not perfectly clear to me what it is you’re trying to say" vs. "It’s not perfectly clear what it is you’re trying to say"

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. It’s not perfectly clear ***to me*** what it is you’re trying to say.
> 2. It’s not perfectly clear what it is you’re trying to say.

What, if any, is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Anyway, does ***to me*** add a bit of arrogance in (1)?

Comment: I would guess the opposite of arrogance, if I had to read into it: they aren't declaring whether it makes sense objectively or for all people, they're just saying "well, ***I*** don't entirely get it[, but maybe that's just me / maybe someone else does]".

Comment: Why ask the same sentence twice?  The bit re arrogance that's tacked on here could have been edited into your [first question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14009/its-not-perfectly-clear-to-me-what-it-is-youre-trying-to-say-vs-its-not-p)

Comment: @jwpat7 One question is about "it is", and the other question is about "to me".  They're different questions, although they're about the same source material.

Comment: As snailboat says, this is not a duplicate (though I can see why it might seem to be one to closevoters, at first glance.) user2793, flag this question if it gets closed and I will reopen for you.

Answer (score 1):

**To me** indicates that the thing which you are trying to say is not clear to that person only.

It can be said when you are introducing something to more than one people.

Whereas 2 sentence indicating to say that the thing which you are trying to tell is not at all clear to anyone whoever is listening to you.

Comment: Agreed (native). (1) is the specific case; (2) is the general case.